# Handling Local Notification in objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I am working on an iphone app where I store all the local(and push) notifications for my app. There will be a screen on app which shows all the notifications generated by the app. My question is that can an iphone app know when a local notification for that app is shown. for example, suppose that a local notification is shown, but the user simply ignores that notification, and does not tap on it, so in this situation, can my app somehow find out if the local notification was shown and do some processing on it(for example, store the notification data in sqlite database).

I have tried both "**didFinishlaunchingWithOptions**" and "**didReceiveLocalNotificatios**", but from my understanding, they are invoked when a user laucnhes app by tapping on the notifiaction, is there a method by which I can have the notification data even when user does not tap on the notification.

tldr; can an iphone app handle(process) local notifications even when user does not launch app by tapping the notification.

Comment: May be you can try applicationdidenterbackground but this method will also get called when you launch the app from background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your app wan't get any notification whcih user has ignored. Your app will notified only when user presses view or tap on that notification.